# How to extract text after <br> using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I want to extract text after the first `<br>` (State).

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="location">
    Country
    <br>
    State
    <br>
    City
</div>
```

Currently I can extract all the `<div>` text with:

```
a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get(url)
state = page.at('.location').text
puts state
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can u give me site url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, but you have to understand how a document is represented inside Nokogiri in the DOM.

There are tags, which are Element nodes, and the intervening text, which are Text nodes:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="location">
    Country
    <br>
    State
    <br>
    City
</div>
EOT

doc.at('.location br').next_sibling.text.strip # => "State"
```

Here's what Nokogiri says `<br>` is:

```
doc.at('.location br').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

And the following Text node:

```
doc.at('.location br').next_sibling.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Text
```

And how we access the content of the text node:

```
doc.at('.location br').next_sibling.text # => "\n    State\n    "
```

And again, looking at the `<div>` tag and its next sibling node:

```
doc.at('.location').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
doc.at('.location').next_sibling.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Text
doc.at('.location').next_sibling # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcf58489c7c "\n">
```

By the way, you can access Mechanize's Nokogiri parser to play with the DOM using something like:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new  
page = agent.get('http://example.com')
doc = page.parser

doc.class # => Nokogiri::HTML::Document
doc.title # => "Example Domain"
```

---

> I can't do like this `doc.at('.location br br').next_sibling.text` or `doc.at('.location br').next_sibling.next_sibling.text`

The first assertion is correct, you can't use `'.location br br'` because you can't nest a tag inside a `<br>`, so `br br` is nonsense when writing a CSS selector for HTML.

The second assertion is wrong. You *can* use `next_sibling.next_sibling` but you have to be aware of the tags in the DOM. In your HTML example it doesn't return anything sensible:

```
doc.at('.location br').to_html # => "<br>"
doc.at('.location br').next_sibling.to_html # => "\n    State\n    "
doc.at('.location br').next_sibling.next_sibling.to_html # => "<br>"
```

And getting the `text` of `<br>` would return an empty string since `<br>` can't wrap text:

```
doc.at('br').text # => ""
```

So, you just didn't go far enough:

```
doc.at('.location br').next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.text.strip # => "City"
```

But, if that's the intention with this DOM I'd do it more simply:

```
break_text = doc.search('.location br').map{ |br| br.next_sibling.text.strip }
# => ["State", "City"]
```

Comment: It works, but for example if I wand to select the city I can't do like this `doc.at('.location br br').next_sibling.text` or `doc.at('.location br').next_sibling.next_sibling.text`

Comment: @Rubyx  which site url u want to scrap?

Comment: @Santosh url is [click here](http://annonces-immobilier.vivastreet.com/achat-vente-maison+poitiers-86000/poitiers-ganterie-maison-ann-e-1930-sh-80m2-jardin-garage/140181742). `Class is .kiwii-no-link-color`

Comment: @Rubyx have u check the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try Following.

```
a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get(url)
state = page.search(".kiwii-no-link-color").children[2].text
puts state
```